# Python UnicodeError Issue with PYPDF2

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote a script to crop PDFs if they were over 1300 pts in height.  It works perfectly.  However I want run it on multiple files in multiple directories.  It runs fine for a while and then I get an error.  However, if I run it just on the folder with the file that throws the UnicodeError, the script runs fine.  If I run it on all of the directories, I get an error.  Not sure what to do as I've tried everything I can think of.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "L:\py_test\!pdferizer_recursive.py", line 17, in <module>
    input1 = PdfFileReader(in_f)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 1901, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 274, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 1331, in read
    self._basic_validation(stream)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 1378, in _basic_validation
    f"PDF starts with '{header_byte.decode('utf8')}', "
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

My code looks like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch

source_folder = r'L:\\py_test' + '\\'

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):
  if dirs:
    for dir_names in dirs:
      folders = str(dir_names)
      file_names = os.listdir(os.path.join(path, folders))
      for files in file_names:
        with open(os.path.join(source_folder + folders, files), 'rb') as in_f:
          input1 = PdfFileReader(in_f)
          output = PdfFileWriter()

          numPages = input1.getNumPages()
          print ("document has %s pages." % numPages)

          for i in range(numPages):
            page = input1.getPage(i)
            print (page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_x(), page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y(), page.mediaBox.getUpperLeft_x(), page.mediaBox.getLowerLeft_y())
            if page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y() > 1300:
              page.cropBox.upperRight = (page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_x(), (page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y() - 1220))
              page.cropBox.lowerLeft = (0, page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y())
              output.addPage(page)
              with open(os.path.join(source_folder + folders,files[:-4]) + "_new.pdf", "wb") as out_f:
                output.write(out_f)
                in_f.close()
            else:
              print (dir_names + "\\" + files + ", this document is under 1300 pts")
              in_f.close()
```

Comment: I don't see any recursion in your code, and in fact the error you get has nothing to do with recursion... I suppose at some point you end up trying to read a non-pdf file, hence the error

Comment: There are only pdfs in these folders.

Comment: I switched over to PyPDF4 and the Unicode error becomes a bad EOF file. But again, I can run it on the folder where it finds the EOF and it runs though it fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

It could happen that a file in a particular folder doesn't actually contain 'UTF-8' encoded data, it contains some other encoding. Figure out what that encoding is and use it in the `open call.

For example:

```
with open(os.path.join(source_folder + folders, files), 'rb', encoding='ISO 8859-1') as in_f:
```

**Option 2:**

If the error persists, you could set the **errors** keyword argument to **ignore** to ignore the characters that cannot be decoded.

Note that ignoring characters that **cannot** be decoded can lead to **data loss**.

```
# set errors to ignore
with open(os.path.join(source_folder + folders, files), 'rb', encoding='ISO 8859-1', errors='ignore') as in_f:
```

Comment: Using rb, doesn’t allow you to use encoding or ignore errors as it’s reading document in binary mode, not as text. And the files open file if I just run the script on that folder. So it’s not a problem with the file

Answer (score 0):

There were a few thumb.db files hidden in different directories.  Added a check for just .pdf and it's golden now.

````
# Import Libraries
from pathlib import Path
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch

source_folder = r'L:\\py_test' + '\\'

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):
  if dirs:
    for dir_names in dirs:
      folders = str(dir_names)
      file_names = os.listdir(os.path.join(path, folders))
      for files in file_names:
        if files.endswith('.pdf'):  
          with open(os.path.join(source_folder + folders, files), 'rb') as in_f:
            input1 = PdfFileReader(in_f)
            output = PdfFileWriter()

            numPages = input1.getNumPages()
            print ("document has %s pages." % numPages)

            for i in range(numPages):
              page = input1.getPage(i)
              print (page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_x(), page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y(), page.mediaBox.getUpperLeft_x(), page.mediaBox.getLowerLeft_y())
              if page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y() > 1300:
                page.cropBox.upperRight = (page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_x(), (page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y() - 1220))
                page.cropBox.lowerLeft = (0, page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y())
                output.addPage(page)
                with open(os.path.join(source_folder + folders,files[:-4]) + "_new.pdf", "wb") as out_f:
                  output.write(out_f)
                  in_f.close()
              elif page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y() > 950 and page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_x() < 570:
                page.cropBox.upperRight = (page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_x(), (page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y() - 850))
                page.cropBox.lowerLeft = (0, page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y())
                output.addPage(page)
                with open(os.path.join(source_folder + folders,files[:-4]) + "_new.pdf", "wb") as out_f:
                  output.write(out_f)
                  in_f.close()            
              else:
                print (dir_names + "\\" + files + ", this document is under 1300 pts")
                in_f.close()```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).